# How to cancel alarm programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I used this code to create  an alarm and it works. Please suggest how to cancel that alarm.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
            alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, mEdtTitle.getText()
                    .toString());
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, mTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());

            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mDatePicker.getMonth());
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mDatePicker.getYear());

            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR,
                    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES,
                    calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
startActivity(alarmIntent);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method `cancel(...)` from `AlarmManager`, using the same `PendingIntent` you used to set the alarm. Example:

`this.getAlarmManager().cancel(mAlarmPendingIntent);`
(this refers to the Activity or the Service from which you are cancelling the alarm).

Create the `PendingIntent` as:

`mAlarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, flags);`

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405397/cannot-cancel-the-current-alarm-in-android @CodeWarrior

Comment: Canceling the PendingIntent does not cancel the alarm already set in the alarm clock. It only cancels the PendingIntent which is the ability to set the alarm in the first place. Once it's set, it cannot be unset by canceling the PendingIntent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke the cancel method: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent))

The `PendingIntent` should be same that you have set before with `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Canceling the PendingIntent does not unset the alarm already set in the alarm clock for me.